# Como ubicar puntos en un mapa por su ruta?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-api

Mi problemática actual es que mi **APP** requiere poder ubicar ciertos lugares haciendo uso de la api de **Google Maps**, de los cuales desconozco su longitud y latitud, pero si su ruta o dirección (ejemplo: calle/sector/punto). Actualmente no poseo un código como tal, solo los ejemplos que ofrece la [Documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker). El cual consiste en un simple método el cual ubica un punto por su latitud + longitud, y un titulo.

```
public class MapsMarkerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {
// Include the OnCreate() method here too, as described above.
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
    // and move the map's camera to the same location.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Gracias y espero su pronto apoyo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

> [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) Clase para el manejo de geocodificación y
>   geocodificación inversa. La geocodificación es el proceso de
>   transformación de una dirección de calle u otra descripción de una
>   ubicación en una coordenada (latitud, longitud).

Este es un ejemplo buscando una dirección, en este caso defino Calle, sector, State y Pais (`"Tepeji 22, Roma, Mexico City, CDMX"`).:

```
String loc_address = "Tepeji 22, Roma, Mexico City, CDMX";

Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
List<Address> addresses;
try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName( loc_address, 1);
if (addresses.size() > 0) {
     latitude = addresses.get(0).getLatitude();
     longitude = addresses.get(0).getLongitude();
}
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Log.d(TAG, "latitude: " + latitude +  " ,longitude: " + longitude);
```

Esto da como resultado la latitud y longitud de la descripción:

```
 latitude: 19.4078773 ,longitude: -99.16091279999999
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]